# How to disable content after the content has expired

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I want to disable Content(not to permanently delete the data) after the product has crossed his/her Expiration date

Comment: Please define _Content_

Comment: Do you have a question?  Perhaps some information about what you're trying to implement and where you're stuck?  It sounds like you're referring to an often-implemented concept called a "soft delete" whereby data is retained by queries against that data filter based on some boolean flag or some date/time value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

add a `status` into  product row 
if product is not crossed the set `status` to `enable` and if it has crossed the set status to `disable`.

and according to status you `show/hide` the content.

you sql query to dosplay content like,

```
"select * from tab where status = 'enable'";
```

if your data is too large then suggest to use boolean for status like 0/1 into status column.

Comment: any reason for downvote??

Comment: WHat will be the Sql query?

Comment: i din't down vote sir !!

Comment: ok , you solve your problem?